# Algorithm for integer rounding of result after division of one integer by another whose values may be negative

Tags: c, algorithm, rounding

I am working with C source code that has a function `RptRound()` used in various reports which takes two values, an amount and a second value such as a count, divides them and then rounds the result. The amount value being divided is usually a currency amount such as US dollars times 100 for an amount in cents.

My question is whether the current function being used will provide correct rounding if the value of both `lAmount` and `sDivisor` are negative resulting in a positive result of their division.

Looking into the subject of rounding it appears that it is not nearly so cut and dried as I originally thought. However it appears the intent here was to do a [Round-Half-Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) type of rounding. Or rather Round-Half-Away-From-Zero. However this function only does so if the value of the divisor, `sDivisor` is positive.

The current function is as follows:

```
DCURRENCY RptRound( DCURRENCY lAmount, SHORT sDivisor )
{
    if (sDivisor) {                      /* Not Divide 0 Case */
        D13DIGITS   Quot, Quot1;

        if ( lAmount < 0 ) {
            Quot1 = -5;
        } else {
            Quot1 = 5;
        }
        Quot = lAmount * 10;
        Quot /= (LONG)sDivisor;
        Quot += Quot1;
        Quot /= 10;
        return Quot;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

It looks like so long as `sDivisor` is always positive then this function will give the correct, rounded up result with a positive value of x.5 rounded up to (x + 1) as well as a negative value of -x.5 rounded down (more negative) to (x - 1).

However it appears to me that if both the `lAmount` and the `sDivisor` are both negative resulting in a positive result then the rounding would be incorrect in that the bias value, `Quot1` would be negative when it should be positive. The result would be that x.5 would be rounded to x and not x + 1 if both are negative. Or even worse that x.2 would be rounded to x - 1 if both are negative.

So I thought to replace the above with the following.

```
DCURRENCY RptRound( DCURRENCY lAmount, SHORT sDivisor )
{
    D13DIGITS   Quot = 0;

    if (sDivisor) {                      /* Not Divide 0 Case */
        Quot = lAmount;
        Quot *= 10;                      // multiply by 10 with larger number of digits
        Quot /= sDivisor;
        // add the bias and divide now in case both lAmount and sDivisor are negative.
        // this will get us to the closest whole number value of the result.
        if ( Quot < 0 ) {
            Quot += -5;      // add half of -10 to make more negative
        } else {
            Quot += 5;       // add half of +10 to make more positive
        }
        Quot /= 10;          // divide by 10 to get to nearest whole number of result.
    }

    return Quot;
}
```

With this version if `sDivisor` is negative and `lAmount` is positive, the result is rounded away from zero (result is negative and rounded more negative) as would the result if `sDivisor` is negative and `lAmount` is negative (result is positive and rounded more positive). If `sDivisor` is positive and `lAmount` is positive the result is rounded away from zero (result is positive and rounded more positive) and if `sDivisor` is positive and `lAmount` is negative the result is rounded away from zero (result is negative and rounded more negative).

However my degree of certainty as to this change is considerably reduced after a bit of reading so I am looking for additional feedback.

**Note:** since `DCURRENCY` is currently a `long` this function generates a compiler warning while doing the conversion for the returned value. This will disappear once `DCURRENCY` becomes a `long long` which is same as `D13DIGITS`.

```
warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'D13DIGITS' to 'DCURRENCY', possible loss of data
```

Comment: `Quot = lAmount * 10;` is overflow (UB) for any value near `LONG_MAX/10` or `LONG_MIN/10`.  Other approaches do not need the *10.

Comment: Some sample values of `lAmount,  sDivisor` and expected results would add clarity to your negative cases.  Use of `sDivisor < 0` has alternative interpretations.  IMO, why not used an unsigned divisor and avoid the issue?

Comment: @chux not sure what you mean by other approaches do not need the * 10. Could you elaborate? Also I am not sure what you mean by "Use of `sDivisor < 0` has alternative interpretations". Good point about the overflow and underflow.

Comment: @chux there appear to be cases where counts may go negative for some types of data items so using unsigned divisor doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this original code was written with the idea of division rounding always towards zero with any remainder truncated. The goal of this code was that the truncation would result in rounding up or down towards the nearest whole number rather than truncation with rounding to zero. So the dividend is multiplied by 10 and then divided by the divisor followed by adding a value of half of 10 so that when the result was then divided by 10 the nearest whole number to the floating point representation of the division would result.

Comment: You are likely correct.  Yet rather than 10 and 5, could have used 2 and 1 for wider range or the half/divisor trick mentioned below.

Answer (score 3):

A negative divisor here looks a bit odd so consider an signed one and unsigned one.  The signed function simply negates both operands.

Instead of scaling by 10 and adding +/-5 and dividing by 10, add half the divisor.

```
DCURRENCY RptRoundU(DCURRENCY lAmount, unsigned Divisor) {
  if (Divisor > 0) {
    if  lAmount < 0) {
      lAmount -= Divisor/2;
    } else {
      lAmount += Divisor/2;
    }  
    lAmount /= (LONG) sDivisor;
    return lAmount;
  }
  return 0;
}

DCURRENCY RptRoundS(DCURRENCY lAmount, signed Divisor) {
  return Divisor < 0 ? RptRoundU(-lAmount, 0u-Divisor) : RptRoundU(lAmount, Divisor);
}
```

Comment: The rounding part is ok, but the "else" part of `if (Divisor != 0)` in the `RptRoundU` function might need some consideration?

Comment: @Groo Changed to match OP's original code in the `Divisor==0` case.

Comment: OP is thinking about this.

Comment: @RichardChambers Pedantic code would also handle the cases where overflow may occur like `lAmount += Divisor/2;` and `-lAmount`, yet this seems to be of secondary concern here.

Comment: @chux overflow/underflow during calculations was the reason for the `D13DIGITS` variable type which is a `long long`. This code was originally for a small box that did not support `long long` so there was a 64 bit integer type defined with a set of functions for 64 bit arithmetic using that 64 bit integer type and then converting back to `long`.

Comment: @RichardChambers Going to wider may work in your case, yet `long long` and `long` may be the same range.  IAC, code to handle the edge conditions about doubles the code length -often only of interest in niche programming.  The half divisor trick does remove the need for the *10, so at least you get about one decimal digit back that way.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simply to add or subtract half the divisor value before dividing, as this will round away from zero.

To make the @chux's answer slightly shorter, you can subtract the value only if one of the values is negative, i.e.

```
DCURRENCY RptRound( DCURRENCY lAmount, SHORT sDivisor )
{
    if (!sDivisor)
        return 0; // or some invalid value

    if ((sDivisor < 0) ^ (lAmount < 0)) {
        lAmount -= (sDivisor / 2);
    } else {
        lAmount += (sDivisor / 2);
    }

    return lAmount / sDivisor;
}
```

Additionally, my preference would be to return a special invalid value for division by zero, something like `(long)0x80000000`.

Comment: Interesting use of XOR operator in the `if`. I am loathe to change the return value if division by zero is attempted as I am not sure if the reports expect it to always be a valid calculated value or just zero if the `sDivisor` is zero. Ok so I get the reason for the half divisor value now.

Comment: @RichardChambers: if this is the existing legacy code you are refactoring, leaving `0` would perhaps make sense, just to avoid breaking existing functionality.

Comment: How can I decide if rounding away from zero is always appropriate? I am not sure if this code was deliberately designed this way or if it has merely been an accident that it worked with the data provided or if someone in the field did run into a case where there was an inaccuracy, no one complained.